# Where are the YAML defaults in Wildfly Swarm?

Tags: wildfly-swarm

According to the [official reference guide](https://reference.wildfly-swarm.io/configuration.html), YAML is the recommended way to configure an application in Wildfly Swarm, and the user-provided YAML file is

> applied overtop the absolute defaults that WildFly Swarm provides

What are these absolute defaults? The documentation does not say anything about that.

**EDIT:**

A few defaults are shown in https://wildfly-swarm.gitbooks.io/wildfly-swarm-users-guide/configuration_properties.html, but the defaults for most fractions are missing: Logging, Batch, Mail, Ee, Ejb, Io, Remoting, Transactions, Webservices etc.

Answer (score 0):

The [Wildfly CLI reference](http://wildscribe.github.io/WildFly/11.0/) specifies the defaults for each Wildfly subsystem, e.g. [for the datasources subsystem](https://wildscribe.github.io/WildFly/11.0/subsystem/datasources/data-source/ExampleDS/index.html).

The settings roughly correspond to the Wildfly Swarm yaml configuration. To see how they correspond, check http://docs.wildfly-swarm.io/2018.1.0/